# How to read data from csv file when file name changes at runtime after downloading

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate download csv file and read data from there.

I tried with:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\File\\1453.csv")); 
String [] csvCell;
//while loop will be executed till the last line In CSV.

while ((csvCell = reader.readNext()) != null) {   
String FName = csvCell[0];

String LName = csvCell[1];

String Email = csvCell[2];

String Mob = csvCell[3];

String company = csvCell[4];
```

but the problem is here I need to give the file name while mentioning the path, here I can't write the name as it is getting changed at runtime after downloading. Please suggest

Comment: I would suggest get the latest CSV file name from the folder and use it. I guess there a lot of source codes for this.

Comment: But i cant do it as i have to always download ew file and read data from that

Comment: I mean, ever time you download a file the file gets downloaded to a folder. Obviously, the file with lasted modified in that folder will be the downloaded CSV only. Try to get its name. So in your above code `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\File\\" + variableCSVFileName));`

Answer (score 1):

If the filename is same as the download link (even if it is partial), you can get the link from the download button or whatever element it is using getAttribute("href") and then you can use it to form the filename to read from.

```
    String fileName = driver.findElement("<download_locator>").getAttribute("href")
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\File\\" + fileName)); 
String [] csvCell;
//while loop will be executed till the last line In CSV.

while ((csvCell = reader.readNext()) != null) {   
String FName = csvCell[0];

String LName = csvCell[1];

String Email = csvCell[2];

String Mob = csvCell[3];

String company = csvCell[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? And passing in the parameter from a method?

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\File\\" + provideFileName));
```